# omniauth doesnt register user for some weird reason?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Hi I'm trying to create a oauth registration through omniauth, using buffer2.  Here is what I have so far, the problem I am having now is that I get redirected to the new_user_registration_path.

I do get taken to buffers site, where I accept that the app receives rights.

```
omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def buffer
  @user = User.find_for_buffer(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  else
    session["devise.buffer_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
 end
end
```

and in the model:

```
def self.find_for_buffer(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
 data = access_token.info
 user = User.where(:provider => access_token.provider, :uid => access_token.uid).first
  if user
   user
  else
 user = User.create(
                email: data.email,
                 provider: access_token.provider,
                 uid: access_token.uid,
                 password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                 )
  end
 user
end
```

the site returns me to the new_user_registration_url, and console is saying:

```
INFO -- omniauth: (buffer) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#buffer as HTML
Parameters: {"state"=>"3ee6956fe2d74bf9a114a29cc55c9c70260aba7f0bd402d9",       "code"=>"1/686ea44403ab403d0c6e647338a936f8"}
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."provider" = 'buffer' AND    "users"."uid" = '526362667f9a1f3f5994515a'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 108ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

I've also attached the url for the api documentation they offer, as I'm a rookie it doesn't make all that sense to me, plus their documentation in my opinion is somewhat crappy as-well:
https://bufferapp.com/developers/api

Comment: The issue is definitely that `@user.persisted?` is returning `false`. You can see in the console `ROLLBACK`, which means the `user` is not saved. You must be failing a `user` validation.

Comment: I tried adding devise_parameter_sanitizer for sign up to permit, provider, uid and password. 

Still doesn't work. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

By default with devise, you need to provide an `email` to your `User`.

You're requesting `data.email` but some OAuth providers don't have en email in their response, like [Twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-hash). Your provider doesn't seem to provide an email  when I look at the documentation.

Try to create a user manually providing an email and see what happen:

```
User.create(
  email: "a-manual-entry@domain.com",
  provider: "a-token",
  uid: "1234567890",
  password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
)
```

From here, you have multiple options, but [you should begin here](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/#completing-the-signup-process).